# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /admin/login/ User has no profile

Tags: python, django

learning django and created a new project.
login to admin page through http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin
But after adding profile code for every user I am getting the below error

**Error**

[image: Error screenshot]

user/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image

class Profile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image=models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self):
        super().save()
        img=Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height>300 or img.width >300:
            output_size=(300,300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

user/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm,UserUpdateForm,ProfileUpdateForm

def register(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() # it will save user in database
            #form.cleaned_data is dictionary it will contain the data from form
            username=form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request,f'Your account has been created!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form=UserRegisterForm()

    # instance of UserCreationForm() class will create form in template as we are passing there
    return render(request,'users/register.html',{'form':form})

@login_required()
def profile(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        u_form=UserUpdateForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
        p_form=ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    context={
        'u_form':u_form,
        'p_form':p_form
    }
    return render(request,'users/profile.html',context)
```

users/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email=forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model=User #model will affected will be User as after submitting form user table gonna affect. and below will fields in forms
        fields=['username','email','password1','password2']

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User  # model will affected will be User as after submitting form user table gonna affect. and below will fields in forms
        fields = ['username', 'email']

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Profile
        fields=['image']
```

users/signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

it might be that the Admin profile is not available and it is not creating.any suggestions ?

Comment: you have this line in your code: `user=models.OneToOneField(User)`. That means that you are using the value of another table in this field. And after this error it looks like you did not create `User` first, so it tries to find in User table *not yet existing user*.

Comment: but User model has admin user

Comment: can it be url based problem?

Comment: i dont think as /admin url coming up but when i make login it gives me error

Comment: User model is django inbuilt so no need to creat @Chiefir

Comment: @Darshan Jain yep, the table `User` exists, but does user with name `Darshan Jain ` exist in that table? I mean you have to create `user` firstly, and next create `Profile` to it.

Comment: I just did query in database
>>> user=User.objects.all()
>>> user
<QuerySet [<User: admin>, <User: Darshan>, <User: Newuser>, <User: Vikas>, <User: Kiran>, <User: Divya>]>
>>>

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an admin profile first. Since the admin has no profile, it's showing related objects doesn't exist. I faced a similar situation and I created an admin profile. It worked

Comment: thanks,work for me. I create another user and work for any another user that i crating  and just previous have error in profile so i delete that user and create again that.

Answer (score 2):

-Enter a python terminal in your virtual environment

```
python manage.py shell
```

-Run this, will fix your issue without blowing out the database

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from users.models import Profile
user = User.objects.get(username='enter_admin_user_here')
profile = Profile(user=user)
profile.save()
```

This will add a user profile for the admin user.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and none of the other answers here helped. This is what did the trick:

1. go to users/apps.py  ------

   if your code editor underlines apps with a red line, then click on it , it will request you to install package django-email-users, click the request it will then download  if it doesn't automatically request you can research how to install django- email-users

   else --- go to step 2
2. delete  all your migrations files like(001, 002 and so on) in every app excluding the
   --init--.py (or you will have another problem).
3. delete your media pictures
4. delete db.sqlite
5. run migrate, migrations, migrate, createsuperuser  in that order
6. now if it shows other error that has to do with file path, try to put back your original
   media pictures and repeat steps 2-6 again,

Answer (score 1):

Finally for me I found an answer!

in the setting
installed apps
I register users as 'users' but when i change it to 'users.apps.UsersConfig', it work!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this Ready function from users - app.py file and try
 def ready(self):
        import users.signals

Comment: Did anyone knows what is the answer of this issue? @Darshan

Answer (score 0):

Check if your `users/app.py` file is as follows:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

If it is not as above, then you have not imported the `signals.py` script .

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code to your users/`__init__.py`

```
default_app_config ='users.apps.UsersConfig'
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you delete your db.sqlite3 from your workspace and create new superuser and make migrations also migrate. It worked in my code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).