# ON deployment to heroku: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /admin/login/ User has no profile

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have no problem with regards to the development stage.
The problem is when I deploy my web thru heroku. i got an error everytime I log in or go to my admin..

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /admin/login/
User has no profile.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://azheafaith.herokuapp.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Django Version: 3.1.4
Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
User has no profile.
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py, line 424, in __get__
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.12
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 28 Dec 2020 06:18:42 +0000
```

--any help is highly appreciated..
Thank you

Comment: did you run your migrations and created a superuser in heroku?

Comment: yey thank you I got it. Now I can add users and make use of my admin..

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is redundant. Check the following link for the possible solutions.

[RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /admin/login/ User has no profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52385596/relatedobjectdoesnotexist-at-admin-login-user-has-no-profile)